# Error message pgfplots pgfkeyscurrentname

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to draw a pgfpicture and besides to it add some picture file.

Using the code below, I get the following error message:

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\p
>   gfkeyscurrentname ' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you
>   misspelled it. See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help. ... l.97 \Item R 2pt (180:-40)

What do I have to correct or add in the following code?

```
    \documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}

        \usepackage{multicol} 
        \columnsep=100pt 
        \columnseprule=3pt 
        \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
        \usepackage{times} 
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{graphicx} 
        \graphicspath{{figures/}} 
        \usepackage{booktabs} 
        \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} 
        \usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} 
        \usepackage{wrapfig} 
        \usepackage{xcolor}
        \usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,lipsum}
        \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
        \usepackage{MnSymbol}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
        \usepackage{pst-node}
        \usepackage{tikz-cd} 

        \usepackage{fancybox}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usepackage{subcaption}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{caption}
        \usepackage{algpseudocode}
        \usepackage{lipsum}
        \usepackage{algorithmicx,algorithm}
        \usetikzlibrary{intersections,automata,arrows,positioning,calc}
        \usepackage{ulem}
        \DeclareCaptionFormat{algor}{%
          \hrulefill\par\offinterlineskip\vskip1pt%
            \textbf{#1#2}#3\offinterlineskip\hrulefill}
        \DeclareCaptionStyle{algori}{singlelinecheck=off,format=algor,labelsep=space}
        \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

        \title{Poster}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
        \begin{document}
        \setcounter{section}{1}
        \setcounter{subsection}{1}

        % Shorthands
        \newcommand*\iffdef{\overset{\text{def}}{\iff}}
        \DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
        \DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}

        % Theorem
        \mdtheorem[
          linecolor=NavyBlue,
          frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},
          frametitlebackgroundcolor=NavyBlue,
        ]{Def}{Theorem}

        \begin{multicols}{2}

        text

        \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{center}\begin{tabular}{cc}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6.3,cap=round,>=latex]
          \def\Radius{.3cm}
          \draw (0cm,0cm) circle[radius=\Radius];
          \begin{scope}[
            -{Stealth[round, length=8pt, width=8pt, bend]},
            shorten >=4pt,
            very thin,
          ]
        %    \draw (0.315cm, -0.38cm) arc(-40-3:-40+3:\Radius);
            \draw (-\Radius, 0) arc(180+3:180-3:\Radius);
          \end{scope}
          % draw the two points 
          \fill[radius=.7pt]
            (-20:\Radius) circle[] node[below right] {$e+r$}
            (-40:\Radius) circle[] node[below right] {$0$}
            (-60:\Radius) circle[] node[below right] {$1$}
            (-80:\Radius) circle[] node[below right] {$...$}
            (-220:\Radius) circle[] node[below right] {$e-1$}
            (-240:\Radius) circle[] node[below right] {$e$}
          ;
          \def\Item#1#2(#3:#4){%
            \path[
              decoration={
                text along path,
                text={#1},
                text align=center,
              },
              decorate,
            ]
              (#3:\Radius-#2) arc(#3:#4:\Radius-#2)
            ;
          }
          \Item R 2pt (180:-40)
          \Item E 1pt (180:300)
        \end{tikzpicture}
        &
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{pic.pdf}\\
        (a) & (b) 
        \end{tabular}\end{center}
        \caption[Illustration]{some text}}
        \label{Fig:1}
        \end{figure}



        \end{multicols}
        \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}` and remove the extra `}` you have after your `\caption[]{}`.

You might want to have a look at cleaning up your preamble a bit, you load several packages more than once.

Comment: If anyone has the same error with the calligraphy package, the solution is to use `decorations.text` before `calligraphy`. Afaict, it's a bug in the package.